# Set cookie if cookie is not already set

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

How would I write something like this in ruby

```
 if( !cookies['isActive']){
    cookies['isActive'] = true
  }
```

I was thinking of putting this in the application controller. Or maybe there is a better way.

I'm basically wanting to set a cookie if one is not already set. It should only live for the time the browser is open.

Then on the application view side I want to be able to see if that cookie is set if it isn't then I want to be able to run some script.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Very simple operator: `||=`.

```
cookies[:is_active] ||= true
```

---

Edit according to the comment:

To read/use it in the view, e.g:

```
<% if cookies[:is_active] %>
  You are active now
<% end %>
```

Comment: So this would be in the controller. How would I call it from the view. Meaning how would I read the cookie from the view.